# hotrod implementation with treecache model

Tags: jboss7.x, infinispan

I'm new to Infinispan but I want to implement a hotrod connection to a server that runs Infinispan 7. I'm using RemoteCache to access the cache, but I want to do that using a tree model. My problem is that TreeCacheFactory.createTreeCache onlys accepts Cache but not RemoteCache.

There's any way to do what I want to do?

Thanks a lot.

Manuel

Comment: Cross site posting https://developer.jboss.org/thread/251367. Make sure you provide links between the cross posted sites to make sure people know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. As replied on the [forum](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/251367), RemoteCache does not support batching/transactions, and the tree module requires batch support.